# How to play video using video player on a instantiated(cloned) screen in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Instantiated model have screen(which is a plane) and the video is not playing.I believe it is because it is the cloned model that the video is not working.When I dragged and dropped the screen and the video player to the respective places while running(testing),the video plays.I tried using Getcomponent from screen and tried playing the clip still not working.

```
  public GameObject screen1;
  public GameObject screen2;

  public VideoPlayer vid1;
  public VideoPlayer vid2;



    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            //Debug.Log ("gameobjhect" + gameObject.name);
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Tochpoint1")
            {
                Debug.Log("Touched Point 1");
                if(screen1.gameObject.tag=="Vid1")
                {
                    Debug.Log("1111");

                    vid1.Play();
                }

            }
            else if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Tochpoint2")
            {

                Debug.Log("Touched Point 2");
                if (screen2.gameObject.name == "Vid2")
                {
                    vids2.Play()
                }


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are calling `vids2.Play()`. Did you mean `vid2.Play()`?  Also, are both of those Videos failing to play, or is it just one? If one, which one?

Comment: Also, you never refer to `screen2`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood you wanna switch video clips when your hit test gives some result. So here is a simple example for changing videos. Attach this to your plane.

```
    VideoPlayer video;

    public VideoClip vid1;
    public VideoClip vid2;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        video = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            video.clip = vid1;

        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            video.clip = vid2;
        }
    }
```

Of course you have to manage this according to your needs. Every time you change the clip video will start from the beginning.

Comment: I think the asker wants to play clips on two separate screens.

Comment: But both of his/her if statements are checking `screen1.gameObject.name`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a typo, because why else even mention `screen2`?

Comment: I am not sure i did not understand his logic i thought he wanted to change video clip with two screens etc.

Comment: The problem is if I drag and drop components in the model ,the video will play.But when I make the model prefab and instantiate them,the video will not play.